# event sources in java

Tags: java, event-handling

Herbert Schildt describes the event source as an object that generates an event.
General form-

```
public void addTypeListener(TypeListener el)
```

My question is - where is this method declared and defined. in which class of which package. I have tried google but in vain.
Kindly help!

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this is a method declaration, and should appear either in the class that you will be adding the event to, or some other place that it would be logical for you to call in your context. The question is a bit broad, because it's like asking "where should I declare a method" - to be sure, you can declare it wherever you want. Try asking, "where do I declare the event for my Button class's OnClick?"

Answer (score 0):

An event source can be any class you choose. If you're, like, creating a game, the `Player` class could be an event source. This is a small example for a `Player` class with player listeners.

```java
public class Player {
    public List<PlayerListener> listeners = new ArrayList<PlayerListener>();

    // ...

    public void addPlayerListener(PlayerListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    // ...

    public void firePlayerEvent(PlayerEvent event) {
        for(PlayerListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onPlayerEvent(event);
        }
    }
}
```

The `addPlayerListener(PlayerListener)` method adds an instance of PlayerListener to the list of listeners the `Player` object will notify if some player event was fired (see `firePlayerEvent(PlayerEvent)`).

In case you need some reference, I'm doing a homework for university that includes events. You can check it out at [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/lirtistasya/tum-eidi-console-game/src).